# How to remotely startup or shut down Version One using C#

Tags: c#, iis, versionone

As part of the administration automation, we are looking in the process of how we can automate the shut down and startup of the Version One service.

I understand that its hosted on an IIS server, so it basically boils down to how to shut down and start up a IIS Service.

Also, if possible please let me know if there are any pre-requesites we need to have on the server which hosts the IIS Server in order to remotely shut it down or start it up.

I could see lots of links suggesting we use Microsoft Web Administration API or service controller, since we have to do it remotely, i could not find anything which would use either of the two methods mentioned above.

Comment: Whats the objective behind closing the Version One Service, if its stays open- whats the issue?